# Im trying to upload my website and its says Server Not Found

Tags: web-hosting

I got a domain in HostGator and im trying to upload my files. 
i just uploaded index.php in the public_html folder and whenever i try to open the website its says

```
Server not found

 Firefox can't find the server at www.intellscheduler.com.

Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox 
is permitted to access the Web.
```

what should i do ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you JUST got it then maybe you should wait for DNS propagation?

Link: [When will my domain start working?](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/when-will-my-domain-start-working-propagation)

CHECK YOUR STATUS HERE: [CHECK DNS PROPAGATION](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.intellscheduler.com)

[12 places to check for DNS propagation](http://www.quantawebdesign.com/domain-names/12-places-to-check-dns-propagation.html)

Comment: i got it yesterday, how long does it take ?

Comment: i checked it and it didnt find it.
still not done yet

Comment: I also added a link to check when its going to be online for the world...Check second link

Comment: all of them are red :O

Comment: is the domain correct that i have in the link? if it is then just wait and dont worry..When i changed my site it was red for 1,5 day....There are also other check sites

Comment: You could try to access it through IP to see what happens

Comment: page not found, through IP